# How to uniquely create components in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am a newbie to Vue js learning through a video tutorial I created a products page here every product will have product details and review forms so, the problem is when submitting review form for prodcut1 the same review is being stored for prodcut 2 and  3 and being displayed in their reviews also 
Once see this link `https://codepen.io/lakshmi123__/pen/mdJdrYG`
js code:

```
// This is one vue component named as product
// Every component will have a template,data and methods
var eventBus = new Vue()
//Component1
Vue.component('product', {
  props:{
    premium:{
      type:Boolean,
      required:true
    }
  },
  template:
  `  <div class="product">
     <div class = "row"
      <div class="row ml-2">
       <div class="col">
       <div class="product-image mt-5 ml-4">
       <img v-bind:src="image">
       <div v-for="(variant,index) in variants"          :key="variant.variantId"
       class="color-box ml-3"
       :style="{ backgroundColor:          variant.variantColor }"
      @mouseover="updateProduct(index)">
      </div>
    <div class="product-info ml-3 mt-1">
    <h4><b>{{ title }}</b></h4>
    <!--Here we have written if-else-if using conditions == ,<,-->
    <p v-if="InStock">In Stock</p>
    <p v-else
    :class="{outOf:!InStock}">Out of Stock</p>
    <p>User is premium: {{ premium }}</p>
    <p>Shipping : {{shipping}}</p>
    <!--Here v-show is nothing but it just toggles the visibility of html element on the web page-->
    <p v-show="Shipping">Shipping cost includes</p>
    <span v-if="OnSale">{{ sale }}</span>
    <div class="Product-Details ml-4 mt-4">
    <h4><b>Details</b></h4>
    <ul>
    <li v-for="detail in details">{{ detail }}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cart1 mt-3 mb-3">
    <button id="click" v-on:click="addToCart" 
    :disabled="!InStock"
    :class="{ disabledButton: !InStock }">Add to Cart</button>
    <button id="click" v-on:click="deleteFromCart"
    :disabled="!InStock"
    :class="{ disabledButton: !InStock }">Delete from Cart</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <product-tabs1 :reviews="reviews"></product-tabs1>


     `,
// In this template at the last we are having another component called product-tabs it is actually the another component but
// is nested in the other component called product we will do like this because we want the product-tabs component to be displayed 
// in the product component like that we can implement nesting of components 


    data(){
        return {
            id:1,
            brand:'Vue Mastery',
            product: 'Socks',
            shipping:'Shipping:0',
            selectedVariant:0,
            Shipping:true,
            details:['80%cotton','20%polester','Gender-neutral'],
            selectedVariant : 0,
            variants:[
            {
                variantId: 2234,
                variantColor: "gray",
                variantImage:"gray.jpeg",
                variantQuantity: 10,
            },
            {
                variantId: 2235,
                variantColor: "blue",
                variantImage:"blue.jpeg",
                variantQuantity: 0
            }
            ],
            reviews:[],

            OnSale:false,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        addToCart(){
            this.$emit('add-to-cart')//this emit is used for letting the parent know that the button was clicked
            // since here the add-to-cart is the name of the event  associated with the add-to-cart button

        },
        updateProduct:function(variantImage){
            this.image=variantImage;
        },
        deleteFromCart:function(){
            this.$emit('delete-from-cart')
        },
        updateProduct(index){
            this.selectedVariant = index
            console.log(index)
        },
        addReview(productReview){
            this.reviews.push(productReview)

        }
    },
    computed:{
        title(){
            return this.brand + ' ' + this.product
        },
        image(){
            return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantImage
        },
        InStock(){
            return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantQuantity
        },
        sale(){
            if(this.OnSale){
                return this.brand + ' ' +this.product + ' is on sale!'
            }
            return this.brand + ' ' +this.product + ' is not on sale!'
        },
        shipping(){
            if(this.premium){
                return "Free"
            }
            return 2.99
           }
        },
        mounted() {
        eventBus.$on('review-submitted', productReview => {
          this.reviews.push(productReview)
        })
    }   
})

Vue.component('product-tabs1', {
    props: {
      reviews: {
        type: Array,
        required: false
      }
    },
    template: `
       <div>

        <div>
          <span class="tabs ml-3 mt-3" 
                :class="{ activeTab: selectedTab === tab }"
                v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
                :key="index"
                @click="selectedTab = tab"
          >{{ tab }}</span>
        </div>

        <div v-show="selectedTab === 'Reviews'">
            <p class="para ml-4" v-if="!reviews.length">There are no reviews yet.</p>
            <ul v-else>
                <li v-for="review in reviews">
                  <p>{{ review.name }}</p>
                  <p>Rating:{{ review.rating }}</p>
                  <p>{{ review.review }}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div v-show="selectedTab === 'Make a Review'">
          <product-review1></product-review1>
        </div>

      </div>
    `,
    data() {
      return {
        tabs: ['Reviews', 'Make a Review'],
        selectedTab: 'Reviews'
      }
    }
  })
Vue.component('product-review1',{
    template:

    `
    <form class ="review-form mt-3" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <p v-if="errors.length">
      <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
      <ul>
      <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
      </ul>
      </p>
    <h5> Please give your review</h5>
    <p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input id="name" v-model="name">
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="review">Review:</label>
    <textarea id="review" v-model="review"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
    <select id="rating" v-model.number="rating">
    <option>5</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>2</option>  
    <option>1</option>
    </select>
   </p>
   <p>Would you recommend this product?</p>
   <label>
   Yes
   <input type="radio" value="Yes" v-model="recommend"/>
   </label>
   <label>
   No
   <input type="radio" value="No" v-model="recommend"/>
   </label>
   <p>

   <p>
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </p>
   </form>

    `
    ,
    data(){
        return {
            name:null,
            review:null,
            rating:null,
            recommend:null,
            errors:[]
        }
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit() {
        this.errors = []
        if (this.name && this.review && this.rating && this.recommend) {
          let productReview = {
            name: this.name,
            review: this.review,
            rating: this.rating,
            recommend: this.recommend
          }
          eventBus.$emit('review-submitted', productReview)
          this.name = null
          this.review = null
          this.rating = null
          this.recommend = null
        }
        else {
          if(!this.name) this.errors.push("Name required.")
          if(!this.review) this.errors.push("Review required.")
          if(!this.rating) this.errors.push("Rating required.")
          if(!this.recommend) this.errors.push("Recommend required")
        }
      }
    }
  })

//component2

Vue.component('product2', {
    props:{
        premium:{
            type:Boolean,
            required:true

        }

    },
    template:
    `<div class="product2">
     <div class = "row"
     <div class="row ml-2">
     <div class="col">
     <div class="product-image mt-5 ml-4">
     <img v-bind:src="image">

     <div v-for="(variant,index) in variants" :key="variant.variantId"
     class="color-box ml-3"
     :style="{ backgroundColor: variant.variantColor }"
     @mouseover="updateProduct(index)">
     </div>
     <div class="product-info ml-2 mt-1">
     <h4><b>{{ title }}</b></h4>
     <!--Here we have written if-else-if using conditions == ,<,-->
     <p v-if="InStock">In Stock</p>
     <p v-else
     :class="{outOf:!InStock}">Out of Stock</p>
     <p class="premium  mb-3">User is premium: true</p>
     <img src="free.jpeg" class="freeshi" width="10" height="10">
     <!--Here v-show is nothing but it just toggles the visibility of html element on the web page-->
     <p v-if="Shipping">Shipping cost includes</p>
     <p v-else
     :class="{Noshipping:!Shipping}">Shipping is Free</p>
     <span v-if="OnSale">{{ sale }}</span>
     <div class="Product-Details ml-4 mt-4">
     <h4><b>Details</b></h4>
     <ul>
     <li v-for="detail in details">{{ detail }}</li>
     </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="cart1 mt-3 mb-3">
     <button id="click" v-on:click="addToCart" 
     :disabled="!InStock"
     :class="{ disabledButton: !InStock }">Add to Cart</button>
     <button id="click" v-on:click="deleteFromCart"
     :disabled="!InStock"
     :class="{ disabledButton: !InStock }">Delete from Cart</button>

     </div>
     </div>

     <product-tabs2 :reviews="reviews"></product-tabs2>

     `,


    data(){
        return {
            id:1,
            brand:'Jockey',
            product: 'Socks',
            shipping:'Shipping:0',
            selectedVariant:0,
            Shipping:false,
            details:['Nocotton','Purepolyster','Gender-neutral'],
            selectedVariant : 0,
            variants:[
            {
                variantId: 2234,
                variantColor: "pink",
                variantImage:"pink2.jpg",
                variantQuantity: 10,
            },
            {
                variantId: 2235,
                variantColor: "green",
                variantImage:"green.jpeg",
                variantQuantity: 0
            }
            ],
            reviews:[],
            OnSale:false,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        addToCart(){
            this.$emit('add-to-cart')//this emit is used for letting the parent know that the button was clicked
            // since here the add-to-cart is the name of the event  associated with the add-to-cart button

        },
        updateProduct:function(variantImage){
            this.image=variantImage;
        },
        deleteFromCart:function(){
            this.$emit('delete-from-cart')
        },
        updateProduct(index){
            this.selectedVariant = index
            console.log(index)
        },
        addReview(productReview){
            this.reviews.push(productReview)

        }
    },
    computed:{
        title(){
            return this.brand + ' ' + this.product
        },
        image(){
            return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantImage
        },
        InStock(){
            return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantQuantity
        },
        sale(){
            if(this.OnSale){
                return this.brand + ' ' +this.product + ' is on sale!'
            }
            return this.brand + ' ' +this.product + ' is not on sale!'
        },
        shipping(){
            if(this.premium){
                return "Free"
            }
            return 2.99
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        eventBus.$on('review-submitted', productReview => {
          this.reviews.push(productReview)
        })
    }   
})

Vue.component('product3', {
    props:{
        premium:{
            type:Boolean,
            required:true

        }

    },
    template:
    `<div class="product3">
     <div class = "row"
     <div class="row ml-2">
     <div class="col">
     <div class="product-image mt-5 ml-4">
     <img v-bind:src="image">

     <div v-for="(variant,index) in variants" :key="variant.variantId"
     class="color-box ml-3"
     :style="{ backgroundColor: variant.variantColor }"
     @mouseover="updateProduct(index)">
     </div>
     <div class="product-info ml-3 mt-1">
     <h4><b>{{ title }}</b></h4>
     <!--Here we have written if-else-if using conditions == ,<,-->
     <p v-if="InStock">In Stock</p>
     <p v-else
     :class="{outOf:!InStock}">Out of Stock</p>
     <p>User is premium: {{ premium }}</p>
     <p>Shipping : {{shipping}}</p>
     <!--Here v-show is nothing but it just toggles the visibility of html element on the web page-->
     <p v-show="Shipping">Shipping cost includes</p>
     <span v-if="OnSale">{{ sale }}</span>
     <div class="Product-Details ml-4 mt-4">
     <h4><b>Details</b></h4>
     <ul>
     <li v-for="detail in details">{{ detail }}</li>
     </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="cart1 mt-3 mb-3">
     <button id="click" v-on:click="addToCart" 
     :disabled="!InStock"
     :class="{ disabledButton: !InStock }">Add to Cart</button>
     <button id="click" v-on:click="deleteFromCart"
     :disabled="!InStock"
     :class="{ disabledButton: !InStock }">Delete from Cart</button>

     </div>
     </div>
     <product-tabs3 :reviews="reviews"></product-tabs3>

     `,


    data(){
        return {
            id:1,
            brand:'Paragon',
            product: 'Socks',
            shipping:'Shipping:0',
            selectedVariant:0,
            Shipping:true,
            details:['PureCotton','NoPolyster','Gender-neutral'],
            selectedVariant : 0,
            variants:[
            {
                variantId: 2234,
                variantColor: "red",
                variantImage:"red1.jpeg",
                variantQuantity: 10,
            },
            {
                variantId: 2235,
                variantColor: "black",
                variantImage:"black1.jpeg",
                variantQuantity: 0
            }
            ],
            reviews:[],

            OnSale:false,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        addToCart(){
            this.$emit('add-to-cart')//this emit is used for letting the parent know that the button was clicked
            // since here the add-to-cart is the name of the event  associated with the add-to-cart button

        },
        updateProduct:function(variantImage){
            this.image=variantImage;
        },
        deleteFromCart:function(){
            this.$emit('delete-from-cart')
        },
        updateProduct(index){
            this.selectedVariant = index
            console.log(index)
        },
        addReview(productReview){
            this.reviews.push(productReview)

        }
    },
    computed:{
        title(){
            return this.brand + ' ' + this.product
        },
        image(){
            return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantImage
        },
        InStock(){
            return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantQuantity
        },
        sale(){
            if(this.OnSale){
                return this.brand + ' ' +this.product + ' is on sale!'
            }
            return this.brand + ' ' +this.product + ' is not on sale!'
        },
        shipping(){
            if(this.premium){
                return "Free"
            }
            return 2.99
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        eventBus.$on('review-submitted', productReview => {
          this.reviews.push(productReview)
        })
    }   
})


Vue.component('product-review1',{
    template:

    `
    <form class ="review-form mt-3" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <p v-if="errors.length">
      <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
      <ul>
      <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
      </ul>
      </p>
    <h5> Please give your review</h5>
    <p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input id="name" v-model="name">
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="review">Review:</label>
    <textarea id="review" v-model="review"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
    <select id="rating" v-model.number="rating">
    <option>5</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>2</option>  
    <option>1</option>
    </select>
   </p>
   <p>Would you recommend this product?</p>
   <label>
   Yes
   <input type="radio" value="Yes" v-model="recommend"/>
   </label>
   <label>
   No
   <input type="radio" value="No" v-model="recommend"/>
   </label>
   <p>

   <p>
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </p>
   </form>

    `
    ,
    data(){
        return {
            name:null,
            review:null,
            rating:null,
            recommend:null,
            errors:[]
        }
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit() {
        this.errors = []
        if (this.name && this.review && this.rating && this.recommend) {
          let productReview = {
            name: this.name,
            review: this.review,
            rating: this.rating,
            recommend: this.recommend
          }
          eventBus.$emit('review-submitted', productReview)
          this.name = null
          this.review = null
          this.rating = null
          this.recommend = null
        }
        else {
          if(!this.name) this.errors.push("Name required.")
          if(!this.review) this.errors.push("Review required.")
          if(!this.rating) this.errors.push("Rating required.")
          if(!this.recommend) this.errors.push("Recommend required")
        }
      }
    }
  })

//this is for tabs component to get the tabs at the end for reviews in one and make a review in another tab


//this is for tabs component to get the tabs at the end for reviews in one and make a review in another tab
Vue.component('product-tabs2', {
    props: {
      reviews: {
        type: Array,
        required: false
      }
    },
    template: `
       <div>

        <div>
          <span class="tabs ml-3 mt-3" 
                :class="{ activeTab: selectedTab === tab }"
                v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
                :key="index"
                @click="selectedTab = tab"
          >{{ tab }}</span>
        </div>

        <div v-show="selectedTab === 'Reviews'">
            <p class="para ml-4" v-if="!reviews.length">There are no reviews yet.</p>
            <ul v-else>
                <li v-for="review in reviews">
                  <p>{{ review.name }}</p>
                  <p>Rating:{{ review.rating }}</p>
                  <p>{{ review.review }}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div v-show="selectedTab === 'Make a Review'">
          <product-review2></product-review2>
        </div>

      </div>
    `,
    data() {
      return {
        tabs: ['Reviews', 'Make a Review'],
        selectedTab: 'Reviews'
      }
    }
  })
Vue.component('product-review2',{
    template:

    `
    <form class ="review-form mt-3" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <p v-if="errors.length">
      <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
      <ul>
      <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
      </ul>
      </p>
    <h5> Please give your review</h5>
    <p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input id="name" v-model="name">
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="review">Review:</label>
    <textarea id="review" v-model="review"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
    <select id="rating" v-model.number="rating">
    <option>5</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>2</option>  
    <option>1</option>
    </select>
   </p>
   <p>Would you recommend this product?</p>
   <label>
   Yes
   <input type="radio" value="Yes" v-model="recommend"/>
   </label>
   <label>
   No
   <input type="radio" value="No" v-model="recommend"/>
   </label>
   <p>

   <p>
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </p>
   </form>

    `
    ,
    data(){
        return {
            name:null,
            review:null,
            rating:null,
            recommend:null,
            errors:[]
        }
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit() {
        this.errors = []
        if (this.name && this.review && this.rating && this.recommend) {
          let productReview = {
            name: this.name,
            review: this.review,
            rating: this.rating,
            recommend: this.recommend
          }
          eventBus.$emit('review-submitted', productReview)
          this.name = null
          this.review = null
          this.rating = null
          this.recommend = null
        }
        else {
          if(!this.name) this.errors.push("Name required.")
          if(!this.review) this.errors.push("Review required.")
          if(!this.rating) this.errors.push("Rating required.")
          if(!this.recommend) this.errors.push("Recommend required")
        }
      }
    }
  })
Vue.component('product-tabs3', {
    props: {
      reviews: {
        type: Array,
        required: false
      }
    },
    template: `
       <div>

        <div>
          <span class="tabs ml-3 mt-3" 
                :class="{ activeTab: selectedTab === tab }"
                v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
                :key="index"
                @click="selectedTab = tab"
          >{{ tab }}</span>
        </div>

        <div v-show="selectedTab === 'Reviews'">
            <p class="para ml-4" v-if="!reviews.length">There are no reviews yet.</p>
            <ul v-else>
                <li v-for="review in reviews">
                  <p>{{ review.name }}</p>
                  <p>Rating:{{ review.rating }}</p>
                  <p>{{ review.review }}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div v-show="selectedTab === 'Make a Review'">
          <product-review2></product-review2>
        </div>

      </div>
    `,
    data() {
      return {
        tabs: ['Reviews', 'Make a Review'],
        selectedTab: 'Reviews'
      }
    }
  })
Vue.component('product-review3',{
    template:

    `
    <form class ="review-form mt-3" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <p v-if="errors.length">
      <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
      <ul>
      <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
      </ul>
      </p>
    <h5> Please give your review</h5>
    <p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input id="name" v-model="name">
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="review">Review:</label>
    <textarea id="review" v-model="review"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
    <select id="rating" v-model.number="rating">
    <option>5</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>2</option>  
    <option>1</option>
    </select>
   </p>
   <p>Would you recommend this product?</p>
   <label>
   Yes
   <input type="radio" value="Yes" v-model="recommend"/>
   </label>
   <label>
   No
   <input type="radio" value="No" v-model="recommend"/>
   </label>
   <p>

   <p>
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </p>
   </form>

    `
    ,
    data(){
        return {
            name:null,
            review:null,
            rating:null,
            recommend:null,
            errors:[]
        }
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit() {
        this.errors = []
        if (this.name && this.review && this.rating && this.recommend) {
          let productReview = {
            name: this.name,
            review: this.review,
            rating: this.rating,
            recommend: this.recommend
          }
          eventBus.$emit('review-submitted', productReview)
          this.name = null
          this.review = null
          this.rating = null
          this.recommend = null
        }
        else {
          if(!this.name) this.errors.push("Name required.")
          if(!this.review) this.errors.push("Review required.")
          if(!this.rating) this.errors.push("Rating required.")
          if(!this.recommend) this.errors.push("Recommend required")
        }
      }
    }
  })

var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        premium:false,
        cart:[]
    },
    methods:{
        updateCart(id){
            this.cart.push(id)
        },
        degradeCart(id){
            this.cart.pop(id);
        }
    }


})








/*In this vue methods section we are two types of methods one is normal functions and the other is the computed properties
 In the normal functions I took the addToCart and deleteToCart functions for incrementing and decrementing the items from the cart
 In the computed properties 
 1.there is title(), image(), InStock() methods title() methods is for printing the product name with 
 the brand that means in the title return statement I had returned the brand and product names together.
 2. there is image() method will display image based on selected Variant in default the selected variant is 0 that is gray here and
 if it is 1 then blue color.
 3. there is InStock() method will display the Instock ad outOfStock messages in the front end based on the quantity taken here
 for gray color socks I had took quantity:10 so instock and for blue color I had took quantity:0 so OutofStock will be displayed
 Here we used props A prop is a custom attribute for passing data into our components
 In order to receive props a component should explicitly call the props 
 So for example
  Vue.component('product',{
   props:[message],
   template:`<div>{{message}}</div>,
   data(){...}
  })
  In the props we have called the message and in the html template we had rendered`


  */
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have one eventBus, but all your components listen for review-submitted on it. So whenever anything emits a review, all the components add it.

Typically you would have just one component here and use it multiple times, passing different products as a prop, rather than duplicating the entire component. That is likely the best way to fix this. (This example seems to come from the VueMastery series, and they walk you though that.)

But you could also fix this by adding a product identifier to the review, and having each listener check whether it applies to them. (Remember that this is a toy project. In any real project, there would be some central store, such as Vuex, that managed all the reviews for all the products.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer so now should I need to create another two event buses

Comment: I don't recommend two event busses. The general point of an event bus is to be global. The point of the tutorial you're following is to show how event busses work. In a simple project like this one, you'd generally just use `this.$emit` (rather than `eventBus.$emit`) to send things up your own chain. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events The VueMastery series you're following is quite good IMO. If you're having trouble, I highly recommend going through it a second time. https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-js

Comment: ThankYou I am practising rather than what he is saying in vue mastery tutorial so I strucked in this point